# OpenCV VideoWriter write() function fails on MAC OS in C++

Tags: macos, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I am newbie here. I am working on OpenCV. I am trying to read and write a video file using OpenCV. My code is:

```
VideoCapture inputVideo("input.avi");

    if (!inputVideo.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout << "!!! Input video could not be opened" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Setup output video
    VideoWriter output_cap("output.avi",
                               inputVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC),
                               inputVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS),
                               cv::Size(inputVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), inputVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)),1);

    Mat frame;

    output_cap.open("/private/var/root/Desktop/output.avi",
                    inputVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC),
                    inputVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS),
                    cv::Size(inputVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), inputVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)),1);
    while (true)
    {
        if (!inputVideo.read(frame))
            break;

        imshow("title",frame);

        waitKey(100);
        output_cap.write(frame);
    }
```

Now here my problem is: When I try to write the frames using  **output_cap.write(frame)** , I am getting only 8kb file as my output video file. but the **imshow("title",frame)** function for viewing the frame works fine and views all the frame sequentially. Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no videoWriter for mac os x. You can save them as a jpeg and then stitch them using ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, As u said, i have already tried that way. i extracted all the frames  and audio from working video file using ffmpeg or opencv in a folder and then merge those frames in a video file using ffmpeg command: **ffmpeg -i src_frames_path/image%d.jpg -qscale 0 -r 25 output file** this command gives me a video file. then i merge that video and audio using ffmpeg cmd: **ffmpeg -i src_frames_path/image%d.jpg -i audio_file output videofile** but the audio and video are not synchronized. Am i doing something wrong in this or any other setting for the video. please help me out.

Comment: Can you check framerate of  your input video? Does it exactly match with "-r" parameter of ffmpeg commmand? If it does no, you can try to resample your audio file using ffmpeg-resampler. Or you can use gstreamer. Maybe taht helps you.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by using other fourcc code: 8BPS and SVQ3.

I had a similar problem. When I tried to record video using mac's webcam the

> imshow("title",frame)

function for viewing the frame works fine. But When I tried to write the frames using

> output_cap.write(frame)

I got only 8kb(exactly 414Bytes) file as my output video file.

I tried lots of way but didn't work. Finally install ffmpeg, but still didn't work.

But I saw "QuickTime video" when I type ffmpeg -codecs in terminal. Then I went to [fourcc.org](http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php) and look up for "Quicktime". I got: 8BPS, AVRN, RPZA, SV10, SVQ3 and ZYGO.

I tried them all, and only two works: 8BPS and SVQ3.

My code is :

```
import cv2 
import time

filename = time.strftime("%m-%d-%H-%M-%S") + '.avi' 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
cap.set(3, 640) 
cap.set(4, 480)

size = (int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),
        int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))

fps = 16

fourcc  = cv2.cv.FOURCC('X', 'V', 'I', 'D')     #does not work 
fourcc0 = cv2.cv.FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X')     #does not work 
fourcc1 = cv2.cv.FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')     #does not work 
fourcc2 = cv2.cv.FOURCC('8', 'B', 'P', 'S')     #works, large 
fourcc3 = cv2.cv.FOURCC('A', 'V', 'R', 'N')     #does not work 
fourcc4 = cv2.cv.FOURCC('R', 'P', 'Z', 'A')     #does not work 
fourcc5 = cv2.cv.FOURCC('S', 'V', '1', '0')     #does not work 
fourcc6 = cv2.cv.FOURCC('S', 'V', 'Q', '3')     #works, small 
fourcc7 = cv2.cv.FOURCC('Z', 'Y', 'G', 'O')     #does not work

out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc6, fps, size, True)
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break;

    else:
        print 'Error...'
        break;

cap.release() 
out.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed OpenCV using brew, try to reinstall it using `brew install opencv --with-ffpmeg`.